# rr gem assert_received equivalent in mocha gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-mocha, rr

Now I use **rr** gem to stub Project model count method, and then I replicate index action to check the count method is called or not. I'm planning to use mocha gem but I don't figure out what is the equivalent of `assert_received` method in **mocha** gem. Following code is one of the example of my tests.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "on GET to index" do
    setup do
      stub(Project).count { 30000 }
      get :index
    end

    should "load up the number of gems, users, and downloads" do
       assert_received(Project)     { |subject| subject.count }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "on GET to index" do
    setup do
      Project.stubs(:count).returns(30000)
    end

    should "load up the number of gems, users, and downloads" do
      Project.expects(:count).returns(30000)
      get :index
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this can help, and here is the [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha#quick-start) API.